# Adobe Flash CS6, how to make a mouseover animation

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript, mouseover

I have a text and an image, and i've been trying to do as following: when the mouse is over the image (not both text and image, just the image), the text changes to another one. I've done lots of mouseover animations, but this situation is beyond my knowledge. So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple I think.

Convert the image/text in to a button.

In the over frame, change the color of appearance of the text.

In the hit frame, draw a rectangle on the image. (rectangle = hit area)

Simple?